# How many kangaroos would you have to add to a northern climate before they could start adapting to it?

Tags: mutations

If some enterprising billionaire wanted to introduce Kangaroos to a northern climate such as the northern boreal forest by Fort McMurray in Alberta, would it be possible for the Kangaroo's to survive and adapt to that climate creating a new super kangaroo (which will henceforth be known as the polar-roo)?

How many kangaroos would have to be dumped into the boreal forest before we would have enough to reach the critical mass that some of the kangaroos would be able to adapt and mutate to this new climate and conquer the north?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! While interesting your question doesn't fit the criteria for questions on this site — specifically this question is extremely speculative and consequently no definitive answer is possible.  ——— Please take the time to go through the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: You seem uncertain of the plural of kangaroo. Stick with the oos — oo’s would be possessive.

Comment: Do we know that kangaroos wouldn't adapt perfectly well to a northern climate?  (Or let's say a cooler one, since Australia is in the southern hemisphere.)  It's not as though they have any chance to naturally experience such climes, or migrate to them.  There are kangaroos in Tasmania, which is about as far south as they could get without building boats.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have fixed the plurality of the kangaroos in my question.

Comment: there are (probably still) feral wallabies in the Peaks district http://www.roaches.org.uk/wallabies.html . Not boreal forest by any means, but at least northern hemisphere ...  (I definitely agree that answers to this Q are going to be opinion-based, though)